# Responsive css-grid with only 2 cells

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, css-grid

How can I create a responsive css grid layout for two cells that will choose whether to stack them vertically or horizontally in order to maximize the area of the second cell? (or some approximating heuristic)

[Vertical Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvCi7.png)

[Lorizontal Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L9iJ.png)

Essentially the menu cell should have dimensions (min-content, min-content), and the body cell should be (auto, 100%) or (100%, auto) for the horizontal and vertical case respectively. I'm just not sure how to 1. Use css grids to implement anything close to this behavior, and 2. Use css to choose the horizontal or vertical layout based on the area of the body cell.

Comment: Honestly in this scenario I would rather use flexbox

Comment: By ticking check on right answer you can close the topic that could help future seekers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@media` and set the 2nd cell `width:100%;` for horizontal layout

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rijaul-sk for pointing out the @media tag, I got a solution based off of that but not entirely the same as his.

```
  @media (orientation: landscape) {
    div.ascii {
      grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 2 / span 1;
    }
  }

  @media (orientation: portrait) {
    div.ascii {
      grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 2;
    }
  }

  div.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
    grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
    height: 100%; /*for some reason this is necessary*/
  }
```

Basically you define the grid as 4 cells and have the other one span 2 of them.

Comment: Happy to help you 